# Creating multiple random strings in C

Tags: c, string, random

I have written a code which creates multiple random strings. But every time I print it, only the last string is printed multiple times even though different strings are created every time. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
    static const char alphanum[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    char s[5],*b[5] ;

    int num =0;
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        *b=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            num = rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1);
            s[i] = alphanum[num];
        }

        s[4] = 0;
        printf("%s\t",s);
        b[j] = s;
    }

    for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        printf("\n%s",b[j]);
}
```

Comment: Change `*b=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);` with `b[j]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);`

Comment: Don't use `rand`. Ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, doing e.g. `*b` is the same as `*(b + 0)` which is the same as `b[0]`. That means that when you allocate memory you assign it to the same entry all the time.

Secondly, last in the loop you *overwrite* the pointer and make `b[j]` point to `s`, all the time. So all pointers in `b` will point to the same `s`. That's why all your strings seems to be the same.

Thirdly, you don't *need* to allocate dynamically in the loop, as all strings are of a fixed size. Instead declare `b` as an array of arrays of characters:

```
char b[5][5];
```

Then instead of assigning the pointer, you [copy the string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) into the correct entry in `b`.

---

Lastly, and for future reference, [don't cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you've seeded the random number generator with, for instance, `srand(time(NULL));`, so that it will generate different random number sequences on each run of the program, there is one more flaw in your code:

`s` is a pointer to an array of characters. With the assignment `b[j] = s;`, you only assign `b[j]` the pointer (memory location) of `s`, but not the contents of `s`. Since the memory location of `s` does not change, all entries of `b` contain the same reference to the same string `s`, which has been changed multiple times. To copy the current content of `s` to `b[j]`, use [strcpy()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy), like this.

```
strcpy(b[j], s);
```

Comment: Nice. I haven't noticed the `b[j] = s;`. `strcpy` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I think your should read the `man 3 rand`

In facts you have to "seed" your rand by calling `void srand(unsigned int seed);` one time in the beggining of your application